# What is the most optimal way to solve this in map reduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Input dataset looks like as shown below:

**colA,colB,colc,time**

1,2,1,2012-12-22 12:23:30

1,2,3,2012-12-22 12:23:40

1,2,2,2012-12-22 12:24:20

2,3,1,2012-12-22 12:25:30

And the output will be difference of next time and current time ie., (time+1 - time). Please see the output column to get more information.

**colA,colB,colc,time,output**

1,2,1,2012-12-22 12:23:30,10

1,2,2,2012-12-22 12:23:40,40

1,2,3,2012-12-22 12:24:20,0

2,3,1,2012-12-22 12:25:30,0

Your help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first two columns are supposed to be the key. Use `TextInputFormat` to read the input text file. Mapper should emit a [Text object](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) which would be `colA_colB`. eg. for the data

```
1,2,2012-12-22 12:23:30
1,2,2012-12-22 12:23:40
1,2,2012-12-22 12:24:20
2,3,2012-12-22 12:25:30
```

mapper would get (key, val):

```
<some long integer X1>, "1,2,2012-12-22 12:23:30"
<some long integer X2>, "1,2,2012-12-22 12:23:40"
<some long integer X3>, "1,2,2012-12-22 12:24:20"
<some long integer X4>, "2,3,2012-12-22 12:25:30"
```

The "some long integer" is nothing but the file offset of the line in input file

Mapper should emit below (key, value) pairs of type [Text](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html):

```
"1_2" , "2012-12-22 12:23:30"
"1_2" , "2012-12-22 12:23:40"
"1_2" , "2012-12-22 12:24:20"
"2_3" , "2012-12-22 12:25:30"
```

As you see, the keys are same for the first 3 records and those would sure-shot end up to the same reducer. Reducers would get this:

```
"1_2" , ["2012-12-22 12:23:30", "2012-12-22 12:23:40", "2012-12-22 12:24:20"]
"2_3" , ["2012-12-22 12:25:30"]
```

In the reducer, [get the String from the Text objects](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html#toString%28%29) and parse those to generate [Java Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects. Getting difference between 2 dates would be straight forward after that.

Comment: hi tejas, my bad i think i confused you a little bit..please see the updated description

Comment: is the input data some file ? even with the updated description, i dont think that my initial answer changes.

Comment: yes input data is in file...but the records might not go to single mapper...it might not be continuous...it can be spread across

Comment: Thats fine.. a customized input format would make this happen. Its **getSplits()** method would be doing the work of packing 2 lines together which would be sent to the mapper.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong...i thought since the first 3 columns are keys...it should go through reducer. all similar keys should be grouped together and then perform calculation

Comment: Thanks a lot..one last question would be...doing the difference..how would you recommend doing it ?

Comment: thats ok..i got the highlevel flow :)

Comment: i don't have that much reputation :( But will soon come and upvote :)